# Extra richtext admin textfield for custom posttype with toolbar tabs?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-qtranslate, custom-write-panel

I am trying to add an extra rich text input field (like so, http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-can-i-use-the-tinymce-editor-for-fields-in-my-custom-post-type)

So just by adding the class class="theEditor", brings up tiny mce for my extra textfield. So far so good, but

1/ how do i add the editor toolbar with the wysiwyg/HTML tabs for the newly created textfield?
2/ As i am using the plugin qTranslate i also like to add the language tabs

Any tips?

regards

Comment: for 1/ i just used the meta-box plugin awesome plugin. Still stuck with 2/

Answer (score 1):

Maby you should use the [wp_editor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) instead? Then you have more control of the editor. An example if you have a meta box called "myfield" in the custom post type. If you want a simple editor you can do like this:

```
echo '<form action="" method="post" target="_blank">';
  wp_editor('<p>Some content</p>', 'myfield' );
echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>';
```

If you want more control you can enable stuff in the array like this:

```
$settings = array(
    'wpautop' => true,
    'media_buttons' => false,
    'tinymce' => array(
        'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold,italic,underline,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,fullscreen',
        'theme_advanced_buttons2' => '',
        'theme_advanced_buttons3' => '',
        'theme_advanced_buttons4' => ''
    ),
    'quicktags' => array(
        'buttons' => 'b,i,ul,ol,li,link,close'
    )
);

echo '<form action="" method="post" target="_blank">';
wp_editor('<p>Some more content</p>', 'myfield', $settings );
echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>';
```

Comment: i am stuck to WP 3.1.4 so i can't use wp_editor :( any other suggestions

Comment: Okay, out of curiosity, why are you stuck with Wordpress 3.1.4?

Comment: hmm, thought i already made a comment. About being stuck the hosting still has php 5.1.6